# Regex for hexa decimal combination of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex which will test the combination of hexadecimal string. Specifically, the string must have:

- Atleast one digit in the range 0 - 9,
- At least one digit in the range A - F,
- be 12 characters long.
- String should not start with 0

Currently I am using `var macRegex = new RegExp("^[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$");`. The above regex allow strings like "111111111111" , "000000000000" which i want to avoid . It should allow a string like "944a0c122123"

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not understanding - your samples of invalid input are valid expressions of numbers in base-16

Comment: "111111111111" should not pass since it shall be a combination of both hex and decimal values like "944a0c122123"..

Comment: Oh so you mean your input needs to validate with at least one digit in the 0-9 range and one in the A-F range?

Comment: You could simplify the expression a little to: `var macRegex = /^[\da-f]{12}$/i;`.

Comment: @jdphenix yes .U got it.. 
String like "000000000000" should not pass which is happening with the above mentioned regex.

Comment: Is using RegExp absolutely necessary or will any function that does the job be okay?

Comment: @Bob Regex is better to use than a simple function .

Comment: So I got to thinking about this a little bit - are you validating MAC addresses? It looks like it, and surely someone out there has already written well tested code to make that happen  :)

Comment: @jdphenix yes .. Its for validating the mac address but the so called well tested code (the regex is mentioned in the question )was failing for "0000000000" . :p Thanks for your answer which saved my day :)

Comment: Ehh, well... MAC addresses could start with a 0, for example one of Intel's prefixes is `00:02:3b`. Xerox has a prefix registered that's `00:00:00`. You may want to re-examine the requirements you have.

Comment: @jdphenix Sure ..let me check and update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set of positive lookaheads to do this.

Here's the regex:

```
/(?!0).(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-f])[\da-f]{11}/i

(?!0)                                 Negative lookahead
.                                     Match any character
(?=                                   Positive lookahead
    .*                                Match any character zero to unlimited
    \d                                Match a digit
)
(?=                                   Positive lookahead
    .*                                Match any character zero to unlimited
    [a-f]                             Match a character a-f
)
[\da-f]{11}                           Match any of the valid characters, 12 times
```

You can conceptualize this is a logical AND of the expressions in each lookahead (except for the `.*`).

```js
var regexp = /(?!0).(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-f])[\da-f]{11}/i;
var test1 = "000000000000";
var test2 = "111111111111";
var test3 = "8179acf0871a";
var test4 = "9abzzzzzzzzz";
var test5 = "0179acf0871a";

console.log(regexp.test(test1));
console.log(regexp.test(test2));
console.log(regexp.test(test3));
console.log(regexp.test(test4));
console.log(regexp.test(test5));
```

Here's a snippet that demonstrates similar input samples.

Comment: That returns true for `"8a9zzzzzzzzz"`.

Comment: @jdphenix Thanks ..But this regex has a little problem . It allows "0000000000f0" and which is wrong as it should not allow the string to start with 0 .Can you please check and update the regex accordingly

Comment: It matches `10000000000` that is not allowed. It also matches `qwerty1234567981345679qwerty`

Comment: @jdphenix can you please check what Toto had said  "qwerty1234567981345679qwerty" .

Answer (score 3):

To keep the regular expression simple, I'd separate matching the pattern and checking the length:

```
var re = /^(\d+[a-f]+[\da-f]*|[a-f]+\d+[\da-f]*)$/i;
var s  = '011001aFFA77';
console.log(re.test(s) && s.length == 12); // true

var s  = '000000000000';
console.log(re.test(s) && s.length == 12); // false
```

The pattern to match:

1. one or more digits followed by one or more letters a to f followed by zero or more digits or letters a to f, OR
2. one or more letters a to f followed by one or more digits followed by zero or more digits or letters a to f

then check the length is 12.

#### Edit

To meet the new criterion "*can't start with 0*" (and simplify the expression a bit), the regular expression can be:

```
var re = /^([1-9]\d*[a-f]+|[a-f]+\d+)[\da-f]*$/i;

var s  = '011001aFFA77';
console.log(re.test(s) && s.length == 12); // false

var s  = '000000000000';
console.log(re.test(s) && s.length == 12); // false


var s  = '011001aFFA77';
console.log(re.test(s) && s.length == 12); // false

var s  = 'a11001aFFA77';
console.log(re.test(s) && s.length == 12); // true

var s  = '311001aFFA77';
console.log(re.test(s) && s.length == 12); // true

var s = '0000000000a1';
console.log(re.test(s) && s.length == 12); // false
```

Comment: I stand corrected. Unless I can figure out how to account for invalid characters with my method, yours is superior (largely because it's correct. ;) )

Comment: @jdphenix—I couldn't think of a way to do it in one expression, but I'm not a RegExp guru by any means!

Comment: @RobG It shall not be start with 0 right ? As it gives true for "0000000000a1" . Can you please check it ? –

Comment: @RobG I want to add the length(12) validator in the regex itself . Can you please help me in it ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a non RegExp solution this function should do what you want.

```
function only_hex_len_12(str){

    // if the string is the wrong length return false
    if(str.length!=12) return false;

    var hex_val=parseInt(str,16);
    var dec_val=parseInt(str,10);


    // If the string is dec return false
    if(!isNaN(dec_val)) return false;


    // If the string is not hex return false
    if(isNaN(hex_val)) return false;

    // Otherwise the string is okay so return true
    return true;
}
```

If you want a RegExp solution RobG's answer looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way I'd go:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-f])[1-9a-f][\da-f]{10}[1-9a-f]$/i
```

**Explanation:**

```
/
  ^             : begining of string
  (?=.*\d)      : lookahead, at least one digit
  (?=.*[a-f])   : lookahead, at least one letter in range a-f
  [1-9a-f]      : first character, not zero
  [\da-f]{10}   : ten hex character
  [1-9a-f]      : last character, not zero
  $             : end of string
/i              : case insensitive
```